# Neo4j subgraph of different nodes with different labels and relationship if any

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I recently started using neo4j and its query language "cypher" for working with building/metering data.

My current graph database consists of different nodes (with different labels such as: point,meter,elec,equip ..etc. just to name a few), and each having different properties (not relevant in this context).

What I would like to do, is to get a sub-graph of different nodes which have different labels. For instance I would like to get all the nodes labeled as "point" as well as the ones labeled "equip" and the ones labeled as "meter". To do so I tried the following query:

```
MATCH (p:point)
MATCH (e:equip)
MATCH (m:meter)
RETURN p, e, m
```

However that does not work since: **This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns.**

I am trying to get these so that, if a node labeled "point" is connected to either an "equip" or "meter" node, I would get the relationship. If nothing is connected to the "point" node, it would just be stand alone. Therefore I could have one subgraph with the "point" to "meter"/"equip" connections and visually identify the isolated "point".

I also tried something like:

```
MATCH (p:point)--(e:equip)
RETURN p,e
```

But that only return the "point" nodes which are somewhat connected to an "equip" node. Not giving me the isolated nodes labeled "point" as well.

Looking forward to your input on this (simple case I guess).

Best!

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return each `point` node, along with a list of all its related `equip` nodes, and another list of all its related `meter` nodes.

```
MATCH (p:point)
RETURN p, [(p)--(e:equip) | e] AS es, [(p)--(m:meter) | m] AS ms
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution/clarification. As I am a little bit new to cypher queries, I have to decompose the list building structure you have used. However, this return the desired output. I also feel that it is more computationally efficient (more efficient query) than the previously posted answer. Is there anything related to computational efficiency in your answer?

Comment: If the number of `point` nodes is N then the complexity is just O(N), since the average number of `equip` and `meter` nodes per `point` are constants.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your latest comment? I am not sure to understand it fully.

Comment: [Linear time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time), or `O(N)`, "means that the running time increases at most linearly with the size of the input". The amount of time it takes to return each result row is `1 + E + M`, where `E` and `M` are the average times to find the `equip` and `meter` nodes related to a given `point`, respectively. So the total runtime is `N(1 + E + M)`, which is a linear function on `N`  since `E` and `M` are constants.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clarification, as well as for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

For this specific subset example:

```
MATCH (p:point)--(e:equip)
RETURN p,e
```

If you are displaying a graph in the Neo4j Client it will show the output I think you want to see with a simple query like this (many variations on this will work just as well)

```
MATCH (a:ACTOR), (m:MOVIE)
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(a)--(m)
return a, m, relationships(p)
```

Translated to your dataset, something like this?

```
MATCH (p:point), (e:equip)
OPTIONAL MATCH t=(p)--(e)
return p, e, relationships(t)
```

run this in the neo4j browser and look at the table output, and you'll see the client is simplifying out extra return data as it create the display view (removing nulls, and duplicates)

If your goal is to minimize and restructure the returned data, the best approach may depend on what language you are calling from and how you need/want it formatted, but here is a quick example query using neo4j browser / desktop client that might give you some ideas and help with restructuring what comes back from a cypher query.

```
MATCH (a:ACTOR), (m:MOVIE)
OPTIONAL MATCH t=(a:ACTOR)--(m:MOVIE)
with collect(distinct a) + collect(distinct m) + collect(relationships(t)) as output
return output
```

Translated to your dataset, something like this?

```
MATCH (p:point), (e:equip)
OPTIONAL MATCH t=(p:point)--(e:equip)
with collect(distinct p) + collect(distinct e) + collect(relationships(t)) as output
return output
```

(compare the table output in neo4j client to the previous query)

[Reference article](https://community.neo4j.com/t/avoid-cartesian-product-when-create-relationships/13624/7)

Comment: Thanks for your input! However, I still doubt about the first query step:
    **MATCH (p:point), (e:equip)**
This still constructs a cartesian product between disconnected patterns doesn't it? Otherwise both queries give me the expected result.

Comment: yes it does (but on the database server only, not in the returned results). If it is critical to avoid the cartesian product, the easiest way to avoid that is probably to do multiple queries.

Comment: Alright! Thank you very much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

```
match (n) where n:point or n:equip or n:meter  return n
```

Explanation. You do one match in order to avoid creating a Cartesian product. Using where condition you select modes with either label “point” or “equip”

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.